# Is using Media queries better than Bootstrap if you want to build a responsive webpage using your own customized theme?

Tags: html, css

Please help me, I'm very new to web development. So far I've only learned how to make non-responsive webpages. I'm self-teaching myself everything and I'm getting confused with responsive design. What is the best approach to making a responsive webpage if your project has its own customized theme?

How do you learn all the classes in bootstrap? I'm so lost at using bootstrap, how are you supposed to know all the classes to utilize when you want to make or adjust things?

My mind is scattered right now I may not be asking the exact question that I have in mind.. But basically all I want to know is if I should use media queries for a responsive customized theme webpage or should I learn bootstrap? thanks in advance

Comment: I really like bootstrap but if you are just starting I wouldn't suggest using it. Not because it's too complex or advanced but because I think it's a good idea to understand how some of this stuff works before using frameworks. For now I'd say stick to writing your own media queries. This is what makes a page responsive.

Comment: Adding on to this, the media queries you define are usually based on a set of "breakpoints", ie at what resolutions you would like your various content to differ.  Some people build starting from smallest and work their way up, some start from the largest resolution and work their way down.  It's up to you.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion guys, and moo2u2 GREAT idea, I should start working from small to big resolutions. that way it's easier to implement the queries.

Comment: By the way, how do people who are new to bootstrap learn about all of their classes? What is the quickest way to know which class to use to build things? and lastly, can you still make your own adjustments when you're using Bootstrap? Because from my understanding, bootstrap has a customized theme already implemented in the css, kind of like a CMS?

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap has some ok documentation and starter code for most of their components and snippets on how to use their different css classes.

You can find information about how to use their different classes here:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/

You can find information about how to use their different components (plus code examples) here:
http://getbootstrap.com/components/